# Use of querySelectorAll isn't applying

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I have following code

```
let cardwrap = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-posts .t-entry-visual")
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      var top = window.pageYOffset / 62;
      cardwrap.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + top + 'px, 0px)';
  });
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="portfolio-posts">
   <div class="t-entry-visual"></div>
   <div class="t-entry-visual"></div>
   <div class="second-visual"></div>
   <div class="t-entry-visual"></div>
</div>
```

When I use querySelector I got the transform style working on the first .t-entry-visual element. But when I use querySelectorAll it doesn't apply the style on any element while I want the transform style applied on all .t-entry-visual elements.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a collection of elements. You'll have to iterate over it and set style on each member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through it using `forEach` because `querySelectorAll` doesn‘t return an element but a collection of elements.

```
let cardwrap = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-posts .t-entry-visual");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  var top = window.pageYOffset / 62;
  cardwrap.forEach(function(elmt) {
    elmt.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + top + 'px, 0px)';
  });
});
```

See also:

- [forEach - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
- [querySelectorAll - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do apply forEach in the code?

Comment: But I would really recommend you not to copy and paste my answer but to try to understand, what I did :)

Comment: While w3schools isn’t as bad as it used to be it is still full of inaccuracies and false informations. And it shouldn’t be used as a reference.

Comment: @t.niese Oh really? Ok, I find it quite useful, but I‘ll update my answer

Comment: The problem is that it is hard to figure out what information on w3schools are inaccurate and which not. For `forEach` it the `The forEach() method is not executed for empty elements.` is such an example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, I'll reference to MDN in the future